# Rails out-of-the-box integration testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I can't seem to find anything except Rails' own documentation on its integration testing platform. Why doesn't anyone use it? How did it die out? What are alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails integration test suite was never great, and projects like [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) have since taken over.